# Unable to access protected sub without postback (vb.net)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

For the past few months I have been developing an Exam Generator website through VB.Net. Now I am in the implementation of (Take Exam) page in which the user will take his own exam and then he will be redirected to another page to get the results.

Take exam page is created dynamically (radio buttons, labels and drop down menus for the choices selected by the user), and the values of the questions and answers are retrieved from an SQL Server Database.

Also, this page whenever the user try to access it, or refresh it, the questions and answers will be shuffled. I implemented the shuffle through an SQL command (ORDER BY NEWID()).

My problem is that I need to process the answers of the user once he clicks submit button, but it's really difficult because whenever the user clicks submit the page will postback with different values for each question and answer. I tried to use AJAX but it couldn't help because the sub has to be protected in order to access the elements of the page through Page.FindControl() method.

**Update: I added partial of the code for more explanation.**

```
If (Request.Cookies("user") Is Nothing) Then
        Response.Redirect("~/index.aspx", False)
    ElseIf Request.UrlReferrer = Nothing Then
        Session.Abandon()
        Response.Redirect("~/main.aspx", False)
    Else
        .
        .
        .
        .
        sql = "SELECT * FROM examTime.dbo.questionexam WHERE examID = @eID ORDER BY type, NEWID()"
        cmd.CommandText = sql
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        Try
            da.Fill(dtall)
            Variables.Variables.dtAll = dtall.Clone()
            For i As Integer = 0 To dtall.Rows.Count - 1 Step 1
                Variables.Variables.dtAll.ImportRow(dtall.Rows(i))
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

        If mcqCount > 0 Then
            Dim dtmcq As New DataTable
            dtmcq.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn(3) {New DataColumn("id", GetType(Integer)), New DataColumn("examID", GetType(Integer)), New DataColumn("questionID", GetType(Integer)), New DataColumn("type", GetType(Integer))})
            Dim mcqID As Integer
            Dim dtmcqQC As New DataTable
            Dim dtmcqAns As New DataTable
            Try
                panelQContainer.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<div class='text blue uppercase'>Multiple Choice Questions</div><div class='text grey uppercase small'>"" Choose the correct answer. ""</div>"))
                panelQContainer.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<div class='review-container-content'>"))
                For n As Integer = 1 To mcqCount Step 1
                    dtmcq.ImportRow(dtall.Rows(0))
                    dtall.Rows.RemoveAt(0)
                    dtall.AcceptChanges()
                    mcqID = Integer.Parse(dtmcq.Rows(n - 1).Item(2))
                    sql = "SELECT question, correct FROM examTime.dbo.question WHERE id = @qid"
                    qidP.Value = Integer.Parse(mcqID)
                    cmd.CommandText = sql
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd
                    da.Fill(dtmcqQC)
                    panelQContainer.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<div class='text red uppercase underline'>Question #" & n & ":</div>"))
                    panelQContainer.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<div class='text black'>" & dtmcqQC.Rows(0).Item(0) & "</div>"))
                    panelQContainer.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<table class='t-max'>"))
                    panelQContainer.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<tr><td class='text grey uppercase'><input type='radio' name='mcq" & n & "' value='A' />&nbsp;Answer A.</td>"))
                    panelQContainer.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<td class='text grey uppercase'><input type='radio' name='mcq" & n & "' value='B' />&nbsp;Answer B.</td>"))
                    panelQContainer.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<td class='text grey uppercase'><input type='radio' name='mcq" & n & "' value='C' />&nbsp;Answer C.</td>"))
                    panelQContainer.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<td class='text grey uppercase'><input type='radio' name='mcq" & n & "' value='D' />&nbsp;Answer D.</td></tr>"))

                    sql = "SELECT qAnswer FROM examTime.dbo.answer WHERE questionID = @qid ORDER BY NEWID()"
                    cmd.CommandText = sql
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd
                    da.Fill(dtmcqAns)
                    Dim arrAns As String()
                    arrAns = {dtmcqQC.Rows(0).Item(1), dtmcqAns.Rows(0).Item(0), dtmcqAns.Rows(1).Item(0), dtmcqAns.Rows(2).Item(0)}
                    arrAns = Functions.Functions.Shuffle(arrAns)
                    panelQContainer.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<tr><td class=""text blue"">" & arrAns(0) & "</td>"))
                    panelQContainer.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<td class=""text blue"">" & arrAns(1) & "</td>"))
                    panelQContainer.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<td class=""text blue"">" & arrAns(2) & "</td>"))
                    panelQContainer.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<td class=""text blue"">" & arrAns(3) & "</td></table>"))
                    If Not n = mcqCount Then
                        panelQContainer.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<div class='separator dark'></div>"))
                    End If
                    dtmcqQC.Clear()
                    dtmcqAns.Clear()
                Next
                panelQContainer.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("</div>"))
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
End If
```

Your help is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide your relevant code in order to receive a relevant answer. If you want to post information via AJAX, then it's best to post to Web API controller. If you want to do it via a regular submit, then you should explain why your current code isn't working *and include your code*.

Comment: I am sorry. Question has been updated with the code.

Comment: You provided a code dump, but you haven't explained why it doesn't work for your needs. You need to approach this question like you're explaining it to someone who hasn't ever head of your application before.